# Double declaration and initialization of vector in a class, C++?

Tags: c++, class, vector

Good night dear all

I have a question, look i working with classes and in many cases i am using vectors of vector (2D vectors), my code runs quite well. However, i am a bit confused, look in my header file i declared a vector of vectors in my protected variables, then in my cpp file in the constructors section i declared again the vector of vectors, but this time giving the needed sizes and having "0" in all the elements. However, when i tried to use this vector of vectors in my member function, it seems that not dimension was delcared and not "0" values, if i use `.size()`  the output is "0" and i was expecting 3.

However, when i declare again the vectors of vectors in the member (see commented line in the cpp file) function the code gives the 3 and the full matrix which is a 3 X 3, composed by "0".

Why is that? using the constructor is to bassically give the values of the variables.

See the next code, the commented line on the cpp file is on which i have declare again the vector.

the header file is:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix
{
private:
    const int m_nRows;
    const int m_nCols;
protected:
    std::vector <std::vector <double>> MATRIX;

public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols);
    ~Matrix();
    void getMatrix();
};
```

The cpp file is:

```
#include "Matrix.h"

Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    : m_nRows(rows),
    m_nCols(cols)
{
    std::vector <std::vector <double>> MATRIX(m_nRows, std::vector<double>(m_nCols, 0));
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
}

void Matrix::getMatrix()
{
    //std::vector <std::vector <double>> MATRIX(m_nRows, std::vector<double>(m_nCols, 0));
    std::cout << MATRIX.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto& columns : MATRIX)
    {
        for (auto& element : columns)
        {
            std::cout << element << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

The main file is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Matrix.h"

    int main() {
        int rows = 3;
        int cols = 3;
    
        Matrix SmallMatrix(rows, cols);
        SmallMatrix.getMatrix();
    
        system("pause>0");
    }
```

Comment: Look up the meaning of the term "scope".     The commented line declares a variable named `MATRIX` that is (1) local to the function `Matrix::getMatrix()`  (2) a completely different object from the member of `Matrix` named `MATRIX` and (3) ceases to exist when the function returns to the caller.     Incidentally, your constructor does the same thing - it creates a variable named `MATRIX` that is local to the constructor body, so the constructor doesn't actually affect the member named `MATRIX` at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i got the whole point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your constructor:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    : m_nRows(rows),
    m_nCols(cols)
{
    std::vector <std::vector <double>> MATRIX(m_nRows, std::vector<double>(m_nCols, 0));
}
```

you define a brand new variable with the name `MATRIX`, which is totally distinct from the member variable `Matrix::MATRIX`.

To initialize the `Matrix::MATRIX` member variable you should do it in the member initializer list, jut like for the `m_nRows` and `m_nCols` variables:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    : m_nRows(rows),
    m_nCols(cols),
    MATRIX(m_nRows, std::vector<double>(m_nCols, 0))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer now everything works. Just for curiosity What happens when you have a vector like this (011100), and i want to a generate a vector of vectors with the size of 3 X 3 because the previous vector only 3 elements have 1. Then if i want to INITIALIZE MY VECTOR OF VECTORS IN THE INITIALIZER LIST, is not possible right?, because i have to first to pass the vector of 0 and 1. Then do a for loop counting how many 1 i have. Then accoring to the counter, i can initialize my vector of vectors rigth?, or how can i do that in the initializer list?

Comment: @baezacaljo If you want  specific values then you could initialize the vectors and set their sizes using the initializer list as shown in my answer above. Then in the construction function body use functions and loops to set the values of the elements.

Comment: thnks a lot i got it, now its time to read more about the constructors. I really appreciate your aswer.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring another variable named `MATRIX` in the constructor. You have to instead use `resize()` on the `MATRIX` member declared in the class. The initialization of that  `MATRIX` can be like this:

```cpp
MATRIX.resize(m_nRows);
for (int i =0; i<m_nRows; i++){
   MATRIX[i].resize(m_nCols, 0);
}
```